# HDP 2.5 fails on accumulo installation

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, accumulo

I originally had 2.4 on this server. I uninstalled it and now I am trying to install 2.5. I did a cleanup of all components, manually deleting each of them. While reinstalling, it fails on Install, Start & Test step. Below is the error. It appears that it is trying to install accumulo_2_4_0_0_169 which is an older version that was removed.

> 2016-09-01 04:05:35,171 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,178 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,185 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] due to not_if
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,186 - Directory['/tmp/hbase-hbase'] {'owner': 'hbase', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0775, 'cd_access': 'a'}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,188 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,190 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hbase /home/hbase,/tmp/hbase,/usr/bin/hbase,/var/log/hbase,/tmp/hbase-hbase'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u hbase) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,196 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hbase /home/hbase,/tmp/hbase,/usr/bin/hbase,/var/log/hbase,/tmp/hbase-hbase'] due to not_if
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,197 - Group['hdfs'] {}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,198 - User['hdfs'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop', 'hdfs']}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,199 - FS Type: 
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,199 - Directory['/etc/hadoop'] {'mode': 0755}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,200 - Directory['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 01777}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,236 - Initializing 2 repositories
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,237 - Repository['HDP-2.5'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.5.0.0/', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP', 'mirror_list': None}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,252 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-2.5]\nname=HDP-2.5\nbaseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.5.0.0/\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,258 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,264 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]\nname=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21\nbaseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,265 - Package['unzip'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,747 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
>   2016-09-01 04:05:35,747 - Package['curl'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:36,073 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
>   2016-09-01 04:05:36,074 - Package['hdp-select'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
>   2016-09-01 04:05:36,400 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select
>   2016-09-01 04:05:36,884 - Package['accumulo_2_4_0_0_169'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5} 
>   2016-09-01 04:05:37,334 - Installing package accumulo_2_4_0_0_169 ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install accumulo_2_4_0_0_169')

Here is the output from yum repolist:

[image: yum repolist output]

Comment: I'd agree with your assessment, Arvind. It seems like Ambari is trying to install the wrong package for some reason. I'm not sure why this is -- You might have some more success asking on http://community.hortonworks.com/ as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have posted there as well. An update: I started all over and removed accumulo from installation.  Now it shows the same error while installing the next service.  Weird.